# Flutter: How to make a button expand to the size of its parent?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create square buttons, but Expanded doesn't seem to work the same as it does with containers. Take the following code for example

```
new Expanded(
 flex: 2,
   child: new Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       new Expanded(
         child:new Row(
           children: <Widget>[
             new Expanded(child: new MaterialButton(...)),
             new Expanded(child: new MaterialButton(....)),

             new Expanded(child: new Container(color: Colors.red)),
             new Expanded(child: new Container(color: Colors.green)),
           ]
         )
       )
     ],
   )
 )

 ....
```

It displays two buttons that are expanded horizontally, but not vertically. At the same time the containers will expand both horizontally and vertically. The same effect occurs if I do the following:

```
new Expanded(
 flex: 2,
   child: new Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       new Expanded(
         child:new Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             new Expanded(child: new MaterialButton(...)),
             new Expanded(child: new MaterialButton(....)),

             new Expanded(child: new Container(color: Colors.red)),
             new Expanded(child: new Container(color: Colors.green)),
           ]
         )
       )
     ],
   )
 )

 ....
```

Where I've changed the Row to Column. The buttons will expand vertically, but not horizontally, while the containers will do both.

Is there a way have my buttons expand to fit their parent both vertically and horizontally?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Add the `crossAxisAlignment` property to your `Row`;

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch
```

Comment: Consider also SizedBox

Answer (score 30):

Wrapping with a `ButtonTheme` with `minWidth: double.infinity` allows to provide constraints

```
ButtonTheme(
  minWidth: double.infinity,
  child: MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('Raised Button'),
  ),
),
```

or after https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/19416 landed

```
  MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: SizedBox.expand(
      width: double.infinity, 
      child: Text('Raised Button'),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 14):

In Flutter 2.+ consider this solution:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, double.infinity), // <--- this line helped me
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Icon(
    Icons.keyboard_return
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also try it

1. Using `SizedBox`

   ```
   SizedBox(
     width: double.maxFinite, // set width to maxFinite
     child: RaisedButton(...),
   )
   ```
2. Use `MaterialButton`'s `minWidth` property.

   ```
   MaterialButton(
     minWidth: double.maxFinite, // set minWidth to maxFinite
     color: Colors.blue,
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text("Button"),
   )
   ```

Answer (score 6):

We can add Button insider Container.

**Solution:**

```
Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Text('NEXT'),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: First, you should always use `SizedBox` instead of `Container` if you are not going to use any of the `Container` property except the `width` and `height`. Second, instead of directly jumping to `double.infinity`, you should try `double.maxFinite`, I can't think of an example at this time, but `double.infinity` can sometimes land you in trouble.

Comment: See this about the diff. I think double.infinite should be used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706455/whats-the-difference-between-double-infinity-and-double-maxfinite-in-dart

Answer (score 5):

you can insert under child:column

crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch

My code
[image]

My result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
MaterialButton(
          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, // set minWidth to width of the device screen
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text("Button"),
        )
```

for reference https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to achieve this using Flexible widget.

Wrap your button in a Flexiable widget and set the fit to Flexfit.tight.

Answer (score -1):

`VisualDensity` is the thing you are looking for. Add it to the `ButtonStyle` object.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: const ButtonStyle(
    visualDensity: VisualDensity(
      horizontal: VisualDensity.maximumDensity,
      vertical: VisualDensity.maximumDensity,
    ),
  ),
  ...
),
```

Answer (score -1):

From documentation and using button theme with `styleFrom` utility static method you can code like this:

```
/// To specify buttons with a fixed width and the default height use
/// `fixedSize: Size.fromWidth(320)`. Similarly, to specify a fixed
/// height and the default width use `fixedSize: Size.fromHeight(100)`.
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('text'),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      fixedSize: const Size.fromWidth(double.infinity),
    ),
  )
```