# Flutter setting width and height of Container widget doesn't work unless using Center to wrap widget ? why?

Tags: flutter

I want to build a swiper. And then limit its height and width. Code like this.

```
Container(
        height: 150,
        width: 350,
        child: Swiper(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Image.network(
              "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            );
          },
          itemCount: 3,
          pagination: SwiperPagination(),
          control: SwiperControl(),
        ),
      );
```

In this case, the final render view will be like this.

[image]

And I find out if I use a Center widget wrap the Container widget that will work.

```
Center(child: Container(
        height: 150,
        width: 350,
        child: Swiper(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Image.network(
              "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            );
          },
          itemCount: 3,
          pagination: SwiperPagination(),
          control: SwiperControl(),
        ),
      ),)
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972393/2252830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because parent witget has no idea how to align its child you should use Align widget