# What's the difference between double.infinity & double.maxFinite in Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

After searching similar topics and especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706455/whats-the-difference-between-double-infinity-and-double-maxfinite-in-dart#:%7E:text=conceptually%20different%20things.-,double.,store%20that%20is%20not%20infinity%20.), I haven't found any solid answer about the difference of those two when using them in widgets.

They both seem to have similar effect, being as big as their parent allows.

Which one of those two is considered as best practice ?

Comment: In the linked question and answer, only `double.infinity` is claimed. That link is insufficient to argue to not use `double.infinity`. What does the flutter documentation (or even other online articles) say?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the difference between double.infinity and MediaQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489513/whats-the-difference-between-double-infinity-and-mediaquery)

Comment: That is to say, this claimed usage of `maxFinite` does not actually appear well-supported.

Comment: I have seen both uses for the same cause that's where my confusion comes from. I think `double.infinity` is the correct way, but i'm not 100% sure.