# How to make the suffixIcon of a TextField cover the entire suffixIcon area?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to design a `TextField` with a button as a `suffixIcon`. The problem is that the button is not covering the entire `suffixIcon` area.

Consider the following example:

```dart
class ActionableTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const ActionableTextField({
    super.key,
    required this.labelText,
    required this.controller,
    required this.prefixIcon,
    required this.suffixIcon,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final IconData prefixIcon;
  final IconData suffixIcon;
  final String labelText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: labelText,
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        prefixIcon: Icon(prefixIcon),
        suffixIcon: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: Icon(suffixIcon),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you take an actual look at the rendering output of `ActionableTextField`, you will notice that the `ElevatedButton` will not completely cover the `suffixIcon` area. How can this be fixed?

The expected rendering output should look as follows:

[image]

The actual rendering output is looking as follows:

[image]

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you can upload an image of what you are trying to achieve. Also, you can specify `boxConstraints` using [suffixIconConstraints](https://api.flutter-io.cn/flutter/material/InputDecoration/suffixIconConstraints.html), id recommend to have a look at that

Comment: @NayefRadwi an image of the expected rendering output was added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like, I mentioned in my comment a you could utilize [suffixIconConstraints](https://api.flutter-io.cn/flutter/material/InputDecoration/suffixIconConstraints.html) to expand the icon by using a `BoxConstraint` with a minimum height.

```dart
  suffixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 55),
```

```dart
class ActionableTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const ActionableTextField({
    super.key,
    required this.labelText,
    required this.controller,
    required this.prefixIcon,
    required this.suffixIcon,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final IconData prefixIcon;
  final IconData suffixIcon;
  final String labelText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: labelText,
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        prefixIcon: Icon(prefixIcon),
        suffixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 55),
        suffixIcon: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: Icon(suffixIcon),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this will enforce the button to have a `minHeight` of 55 and achieves similar to the design you have posted.

Here are other useful questions that could help modify this further

[How to make button width match parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014342/how-to-make-button-width-match-parent)

[How to set the width and height of a button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293503/how-to-set-the-width-and-height-of-a-button-in-flutter)

[Flutter: How to make a button expand to the size of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691052/flutter-how-to-make-a-button-expand-to-the-size-of-its-parent)